# Google Sheet script Error : "Service timed out: Spreadsheets". How to optimize the Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I always get the following error when running a Google Sheet script:

***Service timed out: Spreadsheets (line 10, file "Code")***

The script should copy and paste (values only) an entire sheet from a worksheet to another.
The problem is that the source sheet is quite large and that's why I guess I get the error. The source sheet programmatically populates but it's usually around 8-10k rows

When I use the same script on smaller datasets, it works perfectly.

Unfortunately, I am not a developer but just a marketer, so could anyone help me optimize the script in order for it to run faster and under the 5 minutes limit?

This is script

```
function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA, ssB) {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_id');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var SRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var A1Range = SRange.getA1Notation();
  var SData = SRange.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheet_id');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Script'); 
  ts.clear({contentsOnly: true});
  ts.getRange(A1Range).setValues(SData);
};
```

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: How big is the data range?? Is this function part of another function? Do you know that it is possible to copy the sheet it's self rather than the values? `.copyTo(spreadsheet)`

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the comment
The data range would be around 10k rows and 10 columns.
Say around 100k cells in total
The function is a standalone script, there aren't any other functions.
The problem is I would need to keep the very same sheet as then formulas in other sheets are referring to the same. And the function must run programmatically on a daily basis. But I would try with your suggestion and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: I just did a quick test using 11k rows and 12 cols (random 20 letter text string) your method took 16 seconds and comping the sheet took 3 seconds. What does your data look like? can you provide a sample a sheet?

Comment: oh wow
So it's basically a product feed, which programmatically updates almost every second.
This is a copy of the sheet, where I removed the actual data, but you can see the columns. It usually has around 10k rows of data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uNbZ9-GQL4QWzRfU1sZQ5qOgEZJyMe8aOh8qaMxf13Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: But to be honest, sometimes it works. It's a thing where it works 50% of the times. But you know, it's not enough :)

Also, I get the same error with the very same script for other sheets.
I have another one with maybe 20 columns but just 3k rows max. It looks like a product feed too. The problem here is that it is packed with formulas.
But I don't see how formulas could slow the script down given it should paste values only

Comment: I made a few test on empty worksheets and as you said it worked a in a few seconds.
Maybe it depends on the destination worksheet?
The destination worksheets I am using have around 4-5 sheets packed with formulas. Might be that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function cloneGoogleSheet(ssA, ssB) {
    var targetSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(TARGET_SPREADSHEET_ID);
    var targetSheet = targetSpreadSheet.getSheetByName(TARGET_SHEET_NAME);
    targetSpreadSheet.deleteSheet(targetSheet);
    SpreadsheetApp.openById(SOURCE_SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SOURCE_SHEET_NAME).copyTo(targetSpreadSheet);
}
```

If you want to rename the sheet, then you can use `setName()`

Let me know if there is any bug in my code, or it doesn't work.

References :

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#setnamename

Comment: Hi Umair, 
thanks for your reply.
Unfortunately, it gives me an error
"Target range and source range must be on the same spreadsheet. (line 7, file "Code")"
Apparently, this method is just for copy and paste in the same sheet
But I like how you grouped the openById and getSheetByName objects into one line. It might speed the script up a bit

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: the object targetSpreadSheet.deleteSheet(targetSheet); actually removes the entire sheet itself, not just the data.
Anyway, I think I found at least one of the problems. I substituted all my formulas with ArrayFormulas and now it seems to be working much smoother. Sounds like the target sheet "weight" has an impact on the script speed. This would explain why @james didn't have any problem with the very same script

Comment: Thanks @Jack. Your comment helped me figure out why my 'paste' function with a heap of data (11 cols x 10,000 rows collated from 23 other spreadsheets) wasn't working. I was trying to 'paste' into a formula-heavy spreadsheet that relied on the 'pasted' data. 'Pasting' into a separate spreadsheet and then importing (importRange) that collated data into the formula-heavy sheet is what I'm going to attempt for now.